# Конвертирование HTML to PDF средствами Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, cmd

средставми Google chrome пытаюсь конвертировать html в pdf. Создал для примера файл CMD  (хотя использую System.Diagnostics.Process для выполнения этой команды

```
@echo off > NUL
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --orientation=Landscape --headless --disable-gpu --allow-file-access-from-files --print-to-pdf-no-header --print-to-pdf=C:\test\1.pdf C:\test\1.html
```

Я хочу изменить ориентирование старницы и испльзую параметр `--orientation=Landscape`
Этот параметр где я только не добавлял встроке... игнорируется. Подскажите, где моя ошибка? Спасибо

Comment: на схожий [вопрос](https://superuser.com/questions/1281309/) ответили, что не получится, из-за дефолтного значения переменной landscape.

Comment: А чпо поводу margin-top, margin-left... возможно использвать эти прааметры?

Comment: Я так понял, что этот функционал **не реализовали** в CLI, следовательно нужны сторонние средства для решения этой задачи с помощью Chrome. Предлагаются библиотеки Puppeteer, The CRI library и пр.

Comment: Если можно было бы подключить стиль, как в указано в этом [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/). То есть добавить к коду страницы **<style type="text/css" media="print"> @page {size: landscape;} </style>**, тогда было бы проще. Например, создать HTML-шаблон, который уже будет вызывать URL страницы. Либо напрямую менять код HTML-файла, добавляя вышеуказанную строку.